# C++ Run Failed and Build Successful

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Nodo{
public:
    int valor;
    Nodo *Padre;
    Nodo *HijoIzquierdo;
    Nodo *HijoDerecho;
    Nodo(){
        Padre=HijoIzquierdo=HijoDerecho=NULL;
        valor=0;
    }
};
class Arbol{
public:
    Nodo *Raiz;
    Arbol(){
        Raiz=new Nodo();
        Raiz->valor=5;
        Raiz->HijoDerecho->Padre=Raiz->HijoIzquierdo->Padre=Raiz;
        Raiz->HijoIzquierdo->valor=7;
        Raiz->HijoIzquierdo->HijoIzquierdo->valor=18;
        Raiz->HijoIzquierdo->HijoIzquierdo->Padre=Raiz->HijoIzquierdo;
        Raiz->HijoDerecho->valor=15;
        Raiz->HijoDerecho->HijoIzquierdo->valor=30;
        Raiz->HijoDerecho->HijoIzquierdo->Padre=Raiz->HijoDerecho->HijoDerecho>Padre=Raiz->HijoDerecho;
        Raiz->HijoDerecho->HijoDerecho->valor=8;

    }
    void Arbol::CantidadNodos(Nodo *actual=new Nodo(),int cantNodos){;
        if(actual->HijoDerecho==NULL && actual->HijoIzquierdo==NULL){
            cout<<"El arbol tiene: "<<cantNodos<<" nodos"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        return Arbol::CantidadNodos(actual=actual->HijoIzquierdo,cantNodos++);
    }
};

int main() {
    int opcion;
    Nodo *nodo=new Nodo();
    Arbol *ar = new Arbol();
    cout<<"Ingrese la opcion que desea realizar"<<endl;
    cin>>opcion;
    if(opcion==1){
        ar->CantidadNodos(ar->Raiz,0);
    }
}
```

And when i compile it the build is successful, but it doesn't run, i tried putting some couts to see where is the problem, and the problem is in the following line:

```
Arbol *ar = new Arbol();
```

when the compiler reach that line it crashes, why?

Comment: Have you tried running a debugger and stepping through the code?  That will most likely give you a better idea of where it is failing.

Comment: This is a great time to learn not just about trees but also about tracking down bugs!

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but you don't need dynamic memory allocation for your program. Change all occurrances of `T *t = new T()` with `T t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to revise your requirements**. That said.

```
class Nodo{
public:
    int valor;
    Nodo *Padre;
    Nodo *HijoIzquierdo;
    Nodo *HijoDerecho;
    Nodo(){
        Padre=HijoIzquierdo=HijoDerecho=NULL;
        valor=0;
    }
};
```

This class is not what you want. First of all All of the members are st to NULL. Nothing is allocated for them. So this line and all after it are not legal because `HijoDerecho` is null ptr.

```
Raiz->HijoDerecho->Padre=Raiz->HijoIzquierdo->Padre=Raiz;
```

---

Now even if you try to fix that and allocate space for `HijoIzquierdo` like this

```
Nodo *HijoIzquierdo = new Nodo ();
```

This will keep allocation new `Nodo` for each `HijoIzquierdo` in the new `Nodo`. And soon you will run out of memory.

**So the problem is not just semantic. It is basically a design issue.**

Answer (score 3):

YOur constructor accesses Raiz->HijoDerecho->Padre, but you never assigned HijoDerecho a variable.  The constructor for Nodo assigned it to NULL.  So you're dereferencing a null value

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of `Arbol` creates a new `Nodo` object:

```
Raiz=new Nodo();
```

This uses the default constructor of `Nodo` which sets its members to `NULL`. You then attempt to dereference those members with, for example:

```
Raiz->HijoDerecho->/* ... */;
```

Dereferencing a null pointer results in undefined behaviour.